# How to update relation objects in Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am using Room in Android for persistence and have a class *Profile* which has relations to *Place* and *Timeframe*. I also have a *ProfileWithRelations* class that stored not only the place and timeframe IDs but also the objects. I am using this query in the DAO to get Livedata from the DB and get updates by an observer if something has changed:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM profile")
fun getAllWithRelations(): Flow<List<ProfileWithRelations>>
```

So far so good. If a profile of the *ProfileWithRelations* is changed (i.e. the place is removed), the observer is triggered and the profile object in *ProfileWithRelations* is updated. However, the place object of the *ProfileWithRelations* does not get updated (should change to null as well).

What can I do to automatically update the other objects in *ProfileWithRelations* if the profile changes?

Profile Entity:

```
@Entity(
    indices = [Index(value= ["title"], unique = true)],
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Place::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("place_uid"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("place_id"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    ), ForeignKey(
        entity = Timeframe::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("timeframe_uid"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("timeframe_id"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Profile(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "profile_uid")
    val profileUID: Long,

    var title: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name="place_id")
    var placeId: Long?,

    @ColumnInfo(name="timeframe_id")
    var timeframeId: Long?,

    var active: Boolean
): Serializable
```

ProfileWithRelations:

```
data class ProfileWithRelations (
    @Embedded
    val profile: Profile,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "profile_uid", entityColumn = "place_uid")
    val place: Place?,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "profile_uid", entityColumn = "timeframe_uid")
    val timeframe: Timeframe?,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "profile_uid",
        entityColumn = "detail_action_uid"
    )
    val actions: List<DetailAction>
): Serializable
```

Place Entity:

```
@Entity(indices = [Index(value= ["title", "address"], unique = true)])
data class Place (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "place_uid")
    val placeUID: Long,

    var title: String,

    var address: String?,

    val latitude: String?,

    val longitude: String?,

    var range: Int
): Serializable
```

Timeframe Entity:

```
@Entity
data class Timeframe(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timeframe_uid")
    val timeframeUID: Long,

    var from: Time,

    var to: Time,

    @ColumnInfo(name="am_pm")
    val amPm: Boolean,

    var weekdays: Set<Weekday>
): Serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

**ProfileWithRelations** is not a table/entity, and is really only an extract from the databas. Changes to **ProfileWithRelations** are not applied to the underlying database.

As such you should apply any changes and then, (perhaps optionally) extract again via **`getAllWithRelations`**, probably with the observers observing the tables that form the relationship rather than the extract (depending upon the extract or not extract option).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was hoping that there might be an annotation that could help with that but I guess I have to manually update the relations in the code.

Comment: However, I can update the relations in the app so the UI is up to date, but as soon as I close the app and start it again the ProfileWithRelations suddenly has a place again even if the placeId of the profile is null. Does room use cache (or is it the apps cache)? Shouldn't the app create a new ProfileWithRelations object when the app is started again and realize that there is no placeId for the profile and set the place to null?

Comment: @Wckd_Panda Consider anything you change in ProfileWithRelations temporary, it's only a snapshot of what was in the database at the time it was extracted. So yes you have to push the updates if you want them applied to the database.